Windows installer not detecting drives on dualbooted system
I'm running Windows 11 with Fedora dual booted, or atleast I was, until one day Windows started throwing "Inaccessible Boot Device". To fix that, I'm trying to reinstall Windows without affecting my linux installation. Windows is installed in an SSD while Fedora is on the HDD. But the Windows Installer is unable to detect any drives.
Here's what my disks look like:
disk info
Startup Repair and other similar utils are unable to do anything/even detect my Windows installation, while fedora is able to detect all disks and drives. Both the disks are NTFS, GPT according to Linux disks util. Is there any way to reinstall windows while keeping my fedora? If not, what should I do to start clean and reinstall both Windows and Linux?

It should be possible to reinstall any OS without affecting the others, but the Windows installer must be able to recognize the drives, at least the one where you intend to install it. The drive containing the ESP and, if different, the drive where the system partition should reside.

You may not need to reinstall Windows, the partitions look normal, at first glance. Are you using Grub and when selecting Windows trows that inaccessible boot device error? Have you tried to boot Windows directly? You should before anything else. If it boots directly then you should update it fully, disable Fast Startup and shutdown. Then boot Fedora and run whatever command it uses to update Grub.

@ChanganAuto Tried booting Windows directly, this time it only gave me the option to Troubleshoot Windows or shutdown. Troubleshooting doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the installation.
